# Como parsear un String vacio a Long

Tags: java, java-swing, netbeans-8.2

Tengo un problema que al momento de mi aplicación hay un campo Long, pero ese dato no se llena en diferentes caso pero eso me devuelve un String vacio.
**Ejemplo:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String IdTexto = "";
    Long textoId = Long.valueOf(IdTexto);

    System.out.println("parseo de string a long " + textoId);
}
```

en esa parte como haria para que me retorne un valor al estar vacio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes verificar si la cadena está vacía, si lo está crea, una nueva cadena con el valor "0"

```
Long textoId = Long.valueOf(IdTexto.isEmpty() ? "0" : IdTexto);
```

Comment: Si funciona gracias.